# Left and right sides have a different number of elements when trying to define conditions of a periodic signal

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot periodic signal that has an exponent and time conditions, but I'm getting an error in my line `one_period(-5 <= t1 & t1 < 0) = exp(10*t1 - 10);`.

I'm still very new to MATLAB, so I'm unsure of how to fix this error.

```
T = 1; 
t1 = linspace(0, T, 100 + 1); 
t1(end) = [];
one_period = zeros(size(t1));
one_period(-5 <= t1 & t1 < 0) = exp(10*t1 - 10); 
one_period(0 <= t1 & t1 < 5) = 10;
signal = repmat(one_period, 1, 5);
signal_length = 10;
t_signal_length = linspace(0, T*signal_length, signal_length*100 + 1); 
t_signal_length(end) = [];
figure; 
plot (t_signal_length, signal);
```

Comment: I would recommend that you learn to debug such errors yourself. Start for example with ```clear all``` to start over and to remove all variables from the memory. Then, enter your code line-by-line without the semicolon ```;``` at the end and inspect the output. You can also check the arguments to the functions e.g. invoking only parts of your lines e.g. ```-5 <= t1 & t1 < 0``` or ```exp(10*t1 - 10)``` . This way, I guess, you will be able to find the problem quickly. It is not so hard.

Comment: great thanks! I wasn't sure what the debugging system was for Matlab and I've seen the ```clear all``` before but wasn't sure what it was

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error on this line:

```
one_period(-5 <= t1 & t1 < 0) = exp(10*t1 - 10);
```

Because `t1` is defined as

```
T = 1; 
t1 = linspace(0, T, 100 + 1); 
t1(end) = [];
```

So it is an array between 0 and 1 with 101 elements, then with the last element removed.

And the condition you've used on the erroneous line is not satisfied for any element of `t1`, **which values are you expecting to be between `-5` and `0` in an array defined as values between `0` and `1`?**

Therefore this `-5 <= t1 & t1 < 0` is an array where every value is false, i.e you are assigning *into* zero indices of `one_period`, but you are trying to assign something (on the right of the `=`) which has as many values as `t1`. One of these does not fit into the other!

MATLAB has pretty good [debugging tools](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html), which allow you to add breakpoints, run snippets of code whilst in debug, and view variables as the code progresses. You need to have a clear idea of your expected behaviour and then run through from a breakpoint to identify which part is failing.

If you had a different condition (which actually had some true values) then maybe you just need to use this index on *both* sides of the assignment so that the number of values matches the number of indicies. This would look something like

```
bValid = 0.5 <= t1 & t1 < 0.8; % some condition for a subset within (0,1)
one_period(bValid) = exp(10*t1(bValid) - 10); % Note indexing t1(bValid) too
```

Answer (score 0):

```
T = 1; %-signal period
t1 = linspace(0, T, 100 + 1); %-time series from 0 to T
t1(end) = []; %-remove last value
one_period = zeros(size(t1)); %-make function array (all zeros)
one_period(0 <= t1 & t1 < 0.5) = exp(10*t1(0 <= t1 & t1 < 0.5) - 10); %-define the signal
one_period(0.5 <= t1 & t1 < 1) = exp(10*t1(0.5 <= t1 & t1 < 1) - 10);
signal_length = 5;
signal = repmat(one_period, 1, signal_length); %-replicate the signal 5 times
t_signal_length = linspace(0, T*signal_length, signal_length*100 + 1); %-replicate the time series
t_signal_length(end) = [];
figure; %plot
plot (t_signal_length, signal);
```

Example plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZZQK.jpg

As always, comments are helpful for knowing what your intentions were but here's what I think you were trying to achieve.